# Return the max value of a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula for an excel spreadsheet that will search for a specific column header and return the maximum value in that column. I have tried working with hlookup() but I am unsure how I would be able to return the row number of the array associated with the maximum value for multiple columns. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Do you wish to have a function that can read the contents of a cell containing a header name, then find the max value of that column? Is this formatted as Excel Table or is it just a regular excel sheet table?

Comment: Why not just use max()? It can be fed an entire column, and lookup and reference functions are able to return a column with a given header

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to get the maximum value in the first column with header "x", assuming 26 columns and 100 rows, adjust as required

> =MAX(INDEX(A2:Z100,0,MATCH("x",A1:Z1,0)))

Answer (score 0):

I have data in columns A-C with headers in the first row. I have a cell, D2, which contains a header. The following function gives the max of the column specified by D2:

```
=MAX(OFFSET(A:A,0, MATCH(D2,A1:C1,0) - 1))
```